# docker accessing sqlite from container

Tags: bash, docker, sqlite

I have sqlite3 on the host machine. when I try to access it from interactive container, it errors out as expected saying sqlite3 is not found.

```
/usr/bin/docker run -it --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --mac-address=xxx -h xyz.com python:v4 /bin/bash
```

When I run a script that inserts row into sqlite3 database on the host machine through the container, the container is inserting the row. why? why insertion through a script gives access to sqlite inside a container?

```
/usr/bin/docker run -it -v /scripts:/scripts --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --mac-address=xxx -h xyz.com python:v4 /bin/bash /scripts/python-run.sh
```

The script has the following permissions on the host:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 userx wheel    1132 Jun  5 12:23 python-run.sh
```

Comment: What command are you running inside the container in the first example? What command is the script running?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to your host? localhost from inside a container will not work, because it will resolve to the localhost of your container, and not to the localhost of your local machine. An option could be to run your container on the host network (--net host)